# Get 4 points lying on the plane by given normal

Tags: vector-spaces, surfaces

I would like to create plane using 4 points (which I need to find out), when I know the intersection point of the 2 diagonals in the plane. Next thing I know, that the Y coord of 2 bottom points will be the same and the top 2 Y coords will be the same.

Basicly I want to create that plane in point O, which is (X, Y) big and allways faces some point in space.

Here is a picture, that hopefuly explains it better:
[image: What is (P1, P2, P3, P4)?]

Comment: I do not understand. If point $\sigma$ and vector $\vec n$ are given, so is the plane. What is the point of SizeX and SizeY? Also, are you asking for the plane or for the four points? And which representation of the plane do you want?

Comment: Are you supposing that $P_1P_2P_3P_4$ is a rectangle?

Comment: I want to get the P1, P2, P3 and P4 and yes, they will form a rectangle. The SizeX and SizeY are dimensions of the rectangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you assume that the points form a rectangle, you can see:

$\frac{(P_1+P_3)}{2}=σ $ and $\frac{(P_4+P_2)}{2}=σ $

Moreover if $\vec{n}^{\,}$ is the normal vector of the plane $\implies$
 $\forall \vec{v}^{\,} \in \Pi$ $\ $  $v \cdot n=d  $

Can you continue from here?